# Kotlin - setOnclickListener button is not working

Tags: kotlin, onclicklistener

So the Problem is, I don't know why, but the setOnClickListener is not reacting (Toasting) when I klick it.
Testet it several times and just doesn't react.

```
private lateinit var signInButton: Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    initVariables()
    addListeners()
}

private fun initVariables() {
    signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button)
}

private fun addListeners() {
    signInButton.setOnClickListener {
        println("Hello")
        signIn()
    }
}

private fun signIn() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
}
```

Comment: from where do you override fun onCreate ? is your onCreate funciton called ?

Comment: Does the print of Hello work?

Comment: So I found something like the error, for some reason it through a exeption because it couldn't conect to the Playstore this resultet in Blocking the signIn